# JQuery Code works in Firefox, Opera but not working in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have the following code which works in Firefox-20 and Opera but not in Chrome-26 or IE-10. The keyup functions adds Indian commas to the amounts.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#readyArea").on('change', function() {
        $("#underConstArea").val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
    });

$('.comma').on('keyup', this, function commaFormatted(){
        var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
        var amount = $(this).val().replace(/\,/g,'');
        var a = amount.split('.',2);
        var d = a[1];
        var i = parseInt(a[0],10);
        if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
        var minus = '';
        if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
        i = Math.abs(i);
        var n = new String(i);
        var a = [];
        var cnt=0;
        while(n.length > 2)
        {
            if(cnt == 0)
            {
                var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
                n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
                cnt++;
            }
            else
            {
                var nn = n.substr(n.length-2);
                n = n.substr(0,n.length-2);
            }
            a.unshift(nn);
        }
        if(n.length > 0)
        {
            a.unshift(n);
        }
        n = a.join(delimiter);
        amount = n;
        amount = minus + amount;
        $(this).val(amount);
    });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/46brx/2/). (As I said if I open this link in Firefox or Opera the js works but not in Chrome or IE). There are no js errors on the console either. Do I need to do something specific for Chrome and IE?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, it is the onChange event that is not firing in Chrome and IE. The same is firing in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.43 on OS X and I see the commas just like in Firefox. Are they supposed to look like this: `12,34,56,789` ? (Sorry I'm not familiar with Indian commas)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The late night kinda befuddled my mind. Yes the Commas will appear as in your example. The problem is that the onChange event is not firing in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on Chrome, and the commas did fine, but I never saw the `underConstArea` update, while I did see it do so on Firefox after leaving the textbox.

I'm not sure what is happening there, but I have several ways of fixing it.

First, it seems that whether `$("#readyArea").on('change')` fires is browser dependent.  I don't know why, but it seems that Chrome doesn't throw a change event when you're changing the code.  Maybe it's trying to avoid an infinite loop of changes; I'm not really sure.

If you're happy with the `underConstArea` only updating when the number is done (as it behaves in firefox), you can do so on `focusout` instead of on `change`.  I changed your top lines to

```
$("#readyArea").on('focusout', function() {
    $("#underConstArea").val($(this).val());
});
```

and it worked fine for me in Chrome and Firefox.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/46brx/3/)'s an updated fiddle.

Alternatively, if you want it to update every time the user types, just update `underConstArea` within your `commaFormatted` function.  Just add

```
$("#underConstArea").val(amount);
```

at the bottom of your function.
And the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/46brx/5/) to the second option I offered.  Note that I removed any event catching on `#readyArea`.

Comment: Adding `$(this).trigger('change');` makes the onChange work in Chrome as well. Demo Fiddle jsfiddle.net/46brx/7/. On my page however I used the `focusout` method in conjunction with manually triggering `onchange` i.e. `$(this).trigger('change');`. However I still have'nt been able to figure out why Chrome behaves this way. – Snoopy 37 secs ago edit